# Visual / RAD APL?

Tags: user-interface, ide, language-design, apl, rapid-prototyping

Are there any Visual / [Rapid Application Deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_Application_Development) implementations of [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29)?

If not, what would be needed to implement such a tool?

If it doesn't exist, what would the libraries/interfaces look like for handling standard GUI controls and system calls (file handling, etc)?

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @charles; the tag doesn't even have a wiki.  What does it mean?

Comment: Any tag can have a wiki, whether it has questions or not.  Anyhow, if you do feel the need to use it in future, can you please add at least a summary?  At least then a debate about its meaning would be viable.  Until then, I think a better choice for you would be [ide].

Answer (score 1):

APL2000's APL+WIN system claims to be a RAD product. It surely includes extensive support for "handling standard GUI controls and system calls". So does Dyalog APL.

I suppose what systems count that depends on what you think of as "RAD" and "Visual". Ther is also a product called VisualAPL but I haven't used it.